# Disable HTTP TRACE METHOD Functionality In Oracle IPlanet Webserver

Tags: jakarta-ee, weblogic, trace, iplanet

there was a requirement for me in my project which runs over Oracle iPlanet webserver. as per security concern, we had to disable the HTTP TRACE METHOD after digging and googling over I found Solution which is as follows

1. goto `<iplanet-home-dir>/<server-instance-name>/config`
2. you will find some files like `obj.conf` and `<server-instance-name>-obj.conf`
3. ignore `obj.conf` i also got confuse, when i started googling everyone said that we need to modify in obj.conf but it is wrong way of disabling it. i tried but had no luck.
4. open `<server-instance-name>-obj.conf` file you will find content like below

[image]

5. command to test in this cas i am taking curl utility since most of the hacker uses this to download web content data.

   curl -i -s -k -X 'TRACE' -L http://mahboob.ali.com:56100
6. you will see the following output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this Question itself contains Question and its resolution.

below is the reference of the above Question and Resolution.
http://download.oracle.com/sunalerts/1000718.1.html